Patterns in Strong Graph Products
When computing $C_n^{\boxtimes k}$ where $C_n$ is a cycle graph and $\boxtimes k$ is the kth strong graph product, I noticed that the verticies grow by $n^k$ and the graph is regular with degree $3^k - 1$. Hoping to find patterns in the growth for specific $n$, I made a few tables, but I haven't found any interesting patterns (stable points or cycles) when $n$ is fixed and $k \to \infty$.
What would be the best way to continue?

Aren't $n^k$ and $3^k-1$ already "patterns in the growth"? If not, what are you looking for, exactly?

Hi @MishaLavrov, I am looking to find values of $n$ that lead to a strongly regular, complete, or other specific family that would put more structure on the resulting graph. For example, I think even $n$ always leads to a bipartite graph. Is there a more complete characterization for values of $n$?

That's not correct: no matter what $n$ is, and even if we replace $C_n$ by any nonempty graph, the $\boxtimes k$ power of that graph will not be bipartite for $k\ge 2$, because it will contain $\boxtimes$ shapes. I'm not sure that a question of "does anything interesting happen to any of these graphs?" is answerable without more focus to it.
